# Generate coupons for python flask

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, flask, stripe-payments

I'm trying to generate voucher coupons for my flask application.

I need coupon that are not easily made, that can be read with the proper key and unique through time.

I already tried hashids with something like:

```
from hashids import Hashids
hash_id = Hashids(salt='Super salt', min_length=8)

hash_id.encrypt(30)
# 'voRDznrz'
```

The problem being that the key generated will always be the same.

I also tried itsdangerous for a smarter solution:

```
import itsdangerous
signer = itsdangerous.URLSafeTimedSerializer("Super salt")

coupon = signer.dumps("30 days free!")

signer.load(coupon, max_age=3600*24*30)
# IjMwIGRheXMgZnJlZSEi.Dl1JAQ.u_ilEm7nQ_8XIQt3nbwe31hyyRc
```

The solution is far better but I need to store already used coupon to forbid any re-use. Also the coupon is quite ugly and hard to type for our users.

### Solution:

Okay so I was using Stripe to make my payment, and the answer is in their doc.
Using Stripe in python you can create coupon this way:

```
stripe.api_key = "Your secret api key"

coupon = stripe.Coupon.create(
duration='repeating',
duration_in_month=2,
percent_off=100,)
```

This mean that the coupon will give 2 free month to any subscription, I didn't find how to select a specific product to which the coupon can be applied though.

With the coupon object created you just take his id, this is your coupon code. To bind it to a subscription (and apply it) you do:

```
subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve("Subscription ID")
subscription.coupon = coupon.id
subscription.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Normaly coupons are not hash keys, are just some text like **30FREE** and are stored in a table with a column that indicates if the coupon has been used (and a coupon exists if is in the table).

If you are not using an ORM right now, i recommend **SQLAlchemy** with **Flask-SLQAlchemy**, are very easy to setup and start.

**Note:** you can assign a coupon to a segment of users making a relationship between the coupons table and the users table, and then implement the logic of only a user inside that group can redeem the coupon or something like that.

Comment: You're not wrong but I found a better, replicable way using Stripe.